# How to get 256 colors in GUI Emacs 24 in terminal buffer?

Tags: emacs, colors

I installed Emacs on a Mac via `brew install emacs --cocoa --srgb`.

GUI Emacs itself is running fine. I'm able to use any color theme I want with it. However, when I start a terminal buffer with either `term` or `ansi-term`, and I run `tput colors`, I only get 8. [Trying to display all 256 ANSI colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVEvQ.jpg) via a bash [script](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/78d7d1615d1011c64b9d) gets me just the basic 8 colors.

If I run `list-colors-display`, I get the [basic 8 plus some theming colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgZSE.jpg), but not 256.

This is the GUI version of Emacs, which brings up its own window, so I don't think it has anything to do with the Terminal. But [when I run the same script in Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGlQk.jpg) to display the ANSI colors, I do get all 256, and `tput colors` in Terminal gives me 256, so I know it's not the script's problem.

Did I miss something? Where can I go from here to get 256 colors working in the terminal buffer on GUI Emacs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not miss anything, and there's no way to go from where you are:  Neither `term` nor `ansi-term` [support 256 colors](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2012-05/msg00220.html).

Comment: @Monomo I'm sorry.  I'd have liked to give you a more positive answer, but I'm afraid you are really out of luck in this case.