# Some terminal colors don't show in emacs

Tags: emacs, ansi-colors

I have a function in python called `blue` which wraps a string with the ansi codes to color the string blue. When I run the following in a python interpreter in a normal terminal:

```
>>> blue('hello')
'\x1b[94mhello\x1b[0m'
>>> print blue('hello')
hello
```

the second `hello` is colored blue, as I would expect.

However, if I run the same command in a python interpreter running in emacs, the color is not respected (it's just whatever the default color is). But it's not a case of emacs simply ignoring all color directives, because for example the colors of my `zsh` terminal, `ls`, etc, do show up. Is there a different set of escape codes that emacs respects? Why doesn't emacs color my text?

Comment: Did you try a different color scheme? Is it the same?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an issue with the specific color code, the terminal does not have enough colors (as also stated 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23052188/how-to-get-256-colors-in-gui-emacs-24-in-terminal-buffer) where it says 8 are all you get).

In fact,

```
def blue(s):
     return "\x1b[34m" + s + "\x1b[0m"
```

works for me in the terminal of emacs 24.3.1.

FYI, that is the same color code as `ls` is using given the list from [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/where-is-color-of-ls-command-defined.html).
Actually, `\x1b[01;34m` for bold blue also works.

Testing the [script](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/78d7d1615d1011c64b9d) in the above link yields the following results:

The following text color codes work:

```
\x1b[30m | black
\x1b[31m | red
\x1b[32m | green
\x1b[33m | yellow
\x1b[34m | blue
\x1b[35m | magenta
\x1b[36m | cyan
\x1b[37m | white
```

The corresponding background colors are also supported:

```
\x1b[40m | black
\x1b[41m | red
\x1b[42m | green
\x1b[43m | yellow
\x1b[44m | blue
\x1b[45m | magenta
\x1b[46m | cyan
\x1b[47m | white
```

And on top, the following format codes also work:

```
\x1b[01m | bold
\x1b[04m | underline
\x1b[07m | inverted
```